# How to generate concurrent user report on JMeter

Tags: web-applications, jmeter, load-testing

1 > I have a end to end user scenario and i am running with Total 100 users with ramp up time of 15 Sec. I like to know the max concurrent user for the run. 
Which means For example: out of 100 user, if the 90th user is logging in to app. 1st user is logging out.
So my max concurrent user for the run will be 90.

2 > Additionally, how can i get Total time taken for my run . Which means to execute a single run of 100 user, what is the total time taken. I understand from Aggregate Tree Listener i may able to calculate manually. Is there any other simple,but effective way of doing this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you'll need to extend your JMeter with visualization plugins. See http://jmeter-plugins.org for available list. You may particularly be interested in:

- [Transactions Per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)
- [Server Hits Per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)
- [Composite Timeline Graph](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/)

Or better one [one single plugin](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) which includes all above and more, besides it has different test run results comparison feature.

You may also consider using JMeter Timers to precisely control your scripts and concurrent users behavior, especially:

- [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to fire certain number of requests in the same moment
- [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to set exact load rate in samples per minute.